# How to prevent double submission of the button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have two buttons, one button for increasing a count and other button to submit the count and move to next page. But the error I face is that when I press the button "Proceed", it needs to be pressed twice to move to the next page and also the count is doubled and submitted. The following is the code:

Code:

```
  <button class="btn_success" id="btn_add" value="add areas">Confirm</button>

  <button class="brown-button" id="Proceed" onclick="location.href='gallery.php'; return false;">Proceed &nbsp;</a></button>

    

    var imagecount=0;

    $('.btn_success').click(function(){
      imagecount+=1;
      
      });


    $("#Proceed").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: 'server.php',
                data:{
                    'imagecount':imagecount,
                      },
          success: function(data){
                alert(imagecount);
                }
                })
          });
```

For the above code, the btn_success is used to increment the count and when I press the Proceed button, the count value is submitted and it moves to next page. But, when Proceed button is pressed , the alert pops up twice and the count value submitted is doubled i.e., if the count is 3 when I press Proceed button, it is saved as 6. I want to recitfy this error and save it as value 3.

Can someone help me solve this problem

Comment: you can add disable attribute to the button after click action, and then process.

Comment: I don't see any `id="finish"`button here, did you forget to update your code?

Comment: Add a disable attribute into the button after click bcoz have a collide with other process. You can see with a console

Comment: @xr00tme can you show it where to add

Comment: @Joskaa I have just added an answer incorporating it with a simple [mre].

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I tried your code, but still it keeps submitting twice

Comment: @Joskaa Whatever you do, you can't submit again, because it's disabled. What exactly did you try?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman when I click the Proceed button, the alert pops up but when I click ok for the alert box, i needed to click twice and the count value is store twice

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I tried your code that u have given below and also I tried with " $('#Proceed').attr("disabled", true);" . Both didnt solve my problem

Comment: @Joskaa If it's working in the snippet and not working on your code, unless you show us a [mre], we don't know how to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, in your event handler (which is missing, for `id="finish"` there's no element), you can do something like this:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#finish").click(function () {
    // Cache this to use inside another function.
    $this = $(this);
    $this.prop("disabled", true);
    console.log("Sending AJAX call... You can't re-submit the Finish button again... Please wait...");
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("Got output from server...");
      $this.prop("disabled", false);
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="finish">Finish</button>
```

For a better UX, you can do something like this:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#finish").click(function () {
    // Cache this to use inside another function.
    $this = $(this);
    $this.prop("disabled", true);
    $("#notification").text("Sending AJAX call... You can't re-submit the Finish button again... Please wait...");
    setTimeout(function () {
      $("#notification").text("Got output from server...");
      $this.prop("disabled", false);
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="finish">Finish</button>
<span id="notification"></span>
```